# SQL server report builder show text box only if a field is blank

Tags: sql, text, expression, hide, epicor

I have several text boxes that display information that the field cannot display.

Now when there is data in the field, I don't want the textboxes to display their extra information.  Is there a visibility expression that makes it so the textboxes are only displayed if the field is blank or 0.00?

Edit:
The text box ("TxtCycleTime13") expressions are: "=IIf((Fields!PartNum.Value Like "*16THW-PIF*"), "24.0", "0.00")" right now  -  This makes the text boxes display 24.0 whenever a part number starts with 16THW-PIF

The text box ("TxtCycleTime13") visibility expression are: "=Iif(ReportItems!TxtCycleTime13.Value = "0.00", True, False)" right now. - This makes the text box show ONLY if it has 24.0 (or in other words, if only the part number is 16THW-PIF)

Thanks!

Comment: If which field is blank or 0?? You have said the text box has a visibility expression that shows only if the field is 0 already...

Comment: The visibility expression on the text box shows only if the text box is 24.0...
The field name is CycleTime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True in the expression specifies Hidden, so if the expression returns true the text box will **not** show. To invert this you would simply swap the True and False:

```
=Iif(ReportItems!TxtCycleTime13.Value = "0.00", False, True)
```

This will only show the textbox if the value is 0.
If you want to check  a field instead of the existing textbox, just reference it instead;

```
=Iif(Fields!CycleTime.Value = "0.00", False, True)
```

Comment: Wow...  Guess I'm a little extra slow today.
Thanks!

Edit:  Guess that wasn't what I needed.  I should've explained my issue more thoroughly.  I'll try to figure it out